# How many cents comprise a quarter-tone in 15-EDO?

Tags: theory, quarter-tones

My question is from my MUS 204 course, which is the following: **How many cents comprise a quarter-tone in 15-EDO?**

I believe I am missing one piece of knowledge to answering such a seemingly simple question. First, I understand a quarter-tone is 50 cents and second, I understand the frequency ratio in 15-EDO, correct me if I'm wrong, is 2^1/15 and a cent is 1/1200 of an octave.

I wanted to solve the problem similar to solving for the number of cents in just perfect fifth. (i.e., log of base 2 to the 3/2 = (number of cents)/1200, which is approx. 702 cents.) However, substituting 3/2 for 1/15 produces an incorrect number. (The correct number should be 80 cents.)

**What correct steps must be taken to find the correct answer to the question above?**

Comment: I find this question dubious. IMO there aren't any quarter tones in 15-edo.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I answered on this basis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking 12-EDO as a starting point...

1. 12-EDO divides the octave into 12 semitones and, therefore, 24 quarter tones.
2. The purpose of "cents" is to divide the octave using a linear scale rather than an exponential one.
3. An octave being 1200 cents means that each 12-EDO quarter tone is 1200/24 = 50 cents.

15-EDO is to be treated analogously.

1. 15-EDO divides the octave in 15 "semitones" and, therefore, 30 "quarter tones".
2. It follows, then, that each 15-EDO quarter tone is 1200/30 = 40 cents.

---

As pointed out in the comments, the original textbook question is a dubious one. The concepts of "tone", "semitone", "quarter tone", and "perfect fifth" have specific meanings in 12-EDO that don't transfer — or, at least, don't necessarily transfer — to other EDO systems. It's misleading to speak of semitones and quarter tones, etc., in the context of 15-EDO.

Comment: I do not like it. By the same logic, a “quarter-tone in 22-edo” would be 27.3 cents, but that interval certainly shouldn't be called a quarter tone.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It depends on what is considered a "tone" or "semitone" within the context of the particular tuning system. Given that the question originates in Music 204, I take it to be that they're trying to make a simple analogy with nice math rather than a generalized definition across EDOs. Frankly, I don't like the textbook question that prompted this, for exactly the reason you allude to: it's misleading to refer to 12-EDO concepts (semitone, quarter tone, perfect fifth) in the context of 15- or any other -EDO.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've added a qualifying explanation to the answer. Would value your opinion on whether it offers an adequate caveat.

Comment: Very adequate IMO!

Comment: @Aaron The JI perfect fifth is 3:2, a concept that utterly transcends any tuning system. Semitones can be constructed as 16:15 (diatonic semitone, perfect fourth minus major third), 25:24 (chromatic semitone, major third minus minor third), and weirder combinations. Anything that claims to be called a "quarter tone" needs to be be somewhere half that, necessarily close to the 50 cent range.

Comment: OP quotes the number 80 cents, which makes me think she already knows the information you provided here, and the question is on deriving the number of cents from frequencies.

Comment: Cents are not a linear division of a semitone (or of an octave). If they were linear, a quarter tone wouldn't be 50 cents.

Comment: @PiedPiper Perhaps I used the wrong term. Cents allow for simple multiplication in that x semitones are, say, 50x cents. Is that not linear?

Comment: @Aaron - Isn't a semitone [100 cents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_(music))?

Comment: The underlying frequencies are exponential, just as they are with semitones and octaves.

Comment: @PiedPiper The underlying frequencies, yes, but the math for cents themselves is linear, which I've understood to be the point of using cents.

Comment: @Dekkadeci My error in the comment, yes.

Comment: It seems to me that a cent ought to be defined as 100th of a division in whatever EDO system you're using.  In that light, a quarter tone ought to be 62.5 15-EDO-cents

Comment: @phoog that would make cent scale rather useless in comparing various temperaments or divisions.

Comment: @user1079505 that's true, but there's no particularly compelling reason to measure all temperaments and divisions against 12-tone equal temperament.  The main point, however, is that it makes less sense to adapt the definition of "semitone" to a different equal division of the octave while keeping "cent" related to 12-EDO, because "semitone" predates equal divisions of the octave altogether.  Is a semitone in 31-EDO the 31st part of an octave?  Of course not.

Comment: @phoog Yes, there is a reason, it's needed if you actually want to tune your instrument given way. Consider also, on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament intervals seem to be named based on their similarity to 12-EDO intervals. Calling a 15-EDO step a semitone seems to agree with this convention.

Comment: @user1079505 how does defining "cent" as 1/1200 of an octave instead of as 1/100 of an octave division help anyone tune a flute or a guitar to 15-EDO?  It's not even possible to tune those instruments to 15-EDO.  It's also not necessary to make reference to cents in order to tune any other instrument in 15-EDO; you can just calculate the frequencies directly.

Comment: Because 1/1200 fraction is already an established standard both for scientific research and in commercially available devices, like tuners. Also, as I mentioned, this lets you compare various tunings easily. Yes, cents are not _necessary_ for anything, if you prefer you can calculate frequencies for every purpose. And by the way, Adam Neely shows how to tune bass for 24-EDO, in a similar way you could get 15-EDO. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4KIwA8O9LU

Answer (score 3):

> substituting 3/2 for 1/15 produces an incorrect number

This is where you made a mistake. The formula to calculate number of cents between two frequencies f₁ and f₀ is:

```
1200·log₂(f₁/f₀)
```

For perfect fifth ratio of frequencies f₁/f₀ = 3/2 (in just intonation). However for a semitone in 15-EDO ratio of frequencies is not 1/15. It is 2¹⸍¹⁵.

Then the formulae are as follows: a semitone in 12-EDO has:

```
1200·log₂(2¹⸍¹²) = 1200·(1/12)·log₂(2) = 1200·(1/12) = 100 cents
```

Similarly, a semitone in 15-EDO is

```
1200·log₂(2¹⸍¹⁵) = 1200·(1/15)·log₂(2) = 1200·(1/15) = 80 cents
```

For a "quarter-tone", that is half of a semitone, in 15–EDO substitute 2¹⸍¹⁵ with 2¹⸍³⁰ to obtain 40 cents.

Comment: This is a useful answer, but just know, OP does indicate 2^1/15 for the semitone. You may want to revise your description of where OP misunderstood the math.

Comment: @Aaron OP wrote explicitly she "substituted 3/2 with 1/15" and that's a mistake. It might be a random error or maybe misunderstanding of where which numbers should go, but this is where discrepancy in calculations originates.

Comment: Yes, I understand the error you're correcting. I just think you're explanation of what the error was isn't quite clear.

Comment: ...specifically, the second sentence of your explanation. IMO, that could be usefully clarified.

Comment: @Aaron I tried to clarify the answer. However I don't quite understand what is unclear in sentence "For a perfect fifth ratio of frequencies equals 3/2"?

Comment: IMO it reads better now.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: This question is nonsensical.

[Quarter tones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter_tone) simply don't exist in 12-EDO, since there is no way whatsoever to play one. They only exist in 24-EDO, and if you've added a ton of extra pitches in the middle, you are, clearly, *not using* 12-EDO *in the first place*.

Similarly, 15-EDO literally means one single step is 2^1/15, which comes to 80 cents exactly. That, and all multiples of it, are the **only** intervals that can even *be* played.

Whatever meaning you assign to a quarter tone, it's reasonable to assume it's somewhere around 50 cents, maybe a bit higher. By the plain English reading, 4 of these things should add up to a whole tone, 200 cents or so. 80 cents is just way too far off from 50 - it's more than half again as large!

A 31-cent error, for example, stands between the [actual 7th harmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septimal_whole_tone), less 3 octaves, and the [major second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_second) of 12-EDO. Nobody claims 12-EDO is remotely capable of representing this interval. It just doesn't exist here.

The answer is: in 15-EDO, **there is no playable interval that is remotely usable as a "quarter tone"**.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's issue all. If you could rephrase it in a more polite way, it could make a valid _comment_ about semantics.

Comment: Surely with guitar, trombone, violin, any extra pitches can be played.

Answer (score -1):

TBH I'm a musician and piano tuner, and not a mathematician. But my understanding is that equal temperment tuning on a piano reveals a mathematical discrepancy known as the **Pythagorian Comma**. It has to be said that merely understanding the mathematics of the equally tempered scale does not in and of itself make someone a good piano tuner!

As to quarter-tones, this is not a term used much by musicologists. Instead, the term micro-tones are used. The best examples I can think of where micro-tones are used would be either Arabic music, or Gamalan music (from, say, Bali, Sumatra, etc.).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/75177)