# How many steps in 15-EDO should be used to approximate just perfect fifth?

Tags: theory

My question comes from my MUS 204 course, which is the following: **How many steps in 15-EDO should be used to approximate just perfect fifth?**

I do not know how to calculate the number of steps. However, I know how to calculate the step size by dividing 1200 by 15, which is 80 cents. I also know just perfect fifth (ratio 3/2) is 702 cents.

**What steps do we use to find the correct answer to the question above? (The answer, according to my answer sheet, is 9 steps.)**

Comment: Well, you want ≈700 g of chocolate. You have chocolate bars weighing 80 g each. How many chocolate bars do you need?

Comment: @leftaroundabout The number of chocolate bars I need does not relate to the number of grams I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with [How many cents comprise a quarter-tone in 15-EDO?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/117838/70803) the answer lies in multiplication and division.

There are 1200 cents in an octave, and a 15-EDO step (semitone) is 1200/15 = 80 cents.

We want to know what multiple of 80 is closest to a perfect fifth, which is defined as 702 cents.

80 × 8 = 640; 702 - 640 = 62
80 × 9 = 720; 720 - 702 = 18

Clearly 9 semitones in 15-EDO is closer to a perfect fifth than is 8 semitones.

Comment: Why is '*' deemed to make any sense - I always used '**x**' when I did my sums. Maybe I'm just behind the times?

Comment: @Tim the preferred symbol is actually `×` (U+d7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN), or alternatively `⋅` (U+22c5 DOT OPERATOR), but `*` isn't exactly new either, having been used in pragramming since the 50s. Whether it makes “sense”? – well, all of these are just conventions. At any rate `x` (U+78 LATIN SMALL LETTER X) should not be used, because that's a common _variable name_. (Arguably, the correct symbol for the variable name is actually `` (U+1d465 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL X), but almost nobody uses that and operating systems do not consistently support it.)

Comment: BTW the multiplication sign can be typed in StackExchange answers as `&times;`.

Comment: The first subtraction should be `702 - 640 = 62`.

Comment: Note, however, that defining P5 as 9/15=3/5 of an octave means that the intervals M3=P4 and M7=P8 become indistinguishable.